# Can virtualenvs be made to fall back to user packages instead of system packages?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-jedi

I use [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi) for Python autocompletion in Emacs, but it's not a dependency of my code so I don't want to put it in my `requirements.txt`. (Other developers may not use a Jedi editor plugin, and it's certainly not needed when I deploy to Heroku.)

But Jedi must be available from my virtualenv in order to function, i.e. if I can't

```python
import jedi
```

it doesn't work.

Is there a good way to install Jedi user-globally such that it is available in all of my virtualenvs?

I *think* what I want is to

1. install Jedi into `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` with [`pip`'s `--user` flag](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#cmdoption--user), then to
2. create my virtualenv using the equivalent of [the `--system-site-packages` flag](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#the-system-site-packages-option), but for *user packages* instead of system packages.

My current workaround is to `pip install jedi` in each of my virtualenvs. Then when I add new dependencies I `pip install foo`, `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, then manually remove `jedi` and a few other things from the file before committing. Obviously, this is time-consuming and error-prone.

Does anybody have a better solution?

Comment: Why don't you install it in global site-packages? It would also help to know which Jedi plugin for Emacs you're using.

Comment: @DaveHalter, I'm using [`emacs-jedi`](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi) intalled [via MELPA](https://github.com/milkypostman/melpa/blob/master/recipes/jedi). I do not install Jedi globally and fall back to that because I don't want my virtualenvs to see any of the plethora of other global packages that I have installed... If they are self-contained I can be more confident that I have all of my dependencies listed in `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `virtuenv` `activate`s, it changes several env variables, such as `PATH`, 
`PYTHONHOME`, `PS1`, and so on, to point desired python binary, library, etc. You can change the script to change `PYTHONPATH` to use your user site-packages, namely `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, and possibly your system site-packages. With this setting, pip will search for library in virtual env, and then failover to user/system site-packages. Note that normally activate script does not change `PYTHONPATH` at all.

That is, add the following lines in your `virtual_env/bin/activate`.

```
# in activate script

    # in deactivate function
    if [ -n "$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONPATH" ] ; then
        PYTHONPATH="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONPATH"
        export PYTHONPATH
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONPATH
    fi

# in activate section
if [ -n "$PYTHONPATH" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH"
    PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
fi
```

Comment: If your proposed change is durable, could I suggest you make this change out in the source code?
https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/master/virtualenv_embedded/activate.sh
It doesn't have value to us, that at project-run-time we're always running venv before we activate, resetting those scripts.